# Como fazer uma busca utilizando jpa com buscando pela chave estrangeira

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipse-link

Estou tentando realizar uma busca com jpa, estou com a seguinte query:

```
String jpql = "Select m from Medicamento m where m.usuario_id = ?1";
```

mas ocorre esse erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [Select m from Medicamento m where m.usuario_id = ?1]. 
[34, 46] The state field path 'm.usuario_id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

classe medicamento

```
@Entity
public class Medicamento implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String codigoBarras;
    private String nomeProduto;
    private String principioAtivo;
    private String apresentacao;
    private String laboratorio;
    private String classeTerapeutica;
```

classe usuario

```
@Entity()
public class Usuario implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer idUsuario;
    private Integer idade;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String senha;
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Medicamento> medicamentos = new ArrayList<Medicamento>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teu problema está aqui:

**m.usuario_id = ?1**

Como você está usando jpql, o nome do campo não é o nome da coluna no banco, mas sim o nome do método da entidade de m sem o get, que é Medicamento. Como nela o campo se chama id, a consulta deveria ficar assim:

```
String jpql = "Select m from Medicamento m where m.id = :idUsuario";
```

Veja também que para utilizar queries parametrizadas você deve usar o ":alias". Para informar o valor do alias, você coloca:

```
query.setParameter("idUsuario", id);
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

Answer (score 1):

se vc tem 1 usuário e este possui uma lista de medicamentos e cada medicamento da lista pertence a 1 usuário, podes fazer assim:

```
@Entity()
public class Usuario implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer idUsuario;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "usuario_id")
    private List<Medicamento> medicamentos = new ArrayList<Medicamento>(); 
}

@Entity
public class Medicamento implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id", referencedColumnName = "usuario_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Usuario usuario_id
}
```

Note o MappedBy que diz que Medicamento é o dono da relação, então na query você pode fazer:

```
public Medicamento findMedicamentoByUserID(Long usuario_id) {
    EntityManager manager = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    Query query = null;
    Medicamento medicamento = null;
    try {
        query = manager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Medicamento m where m.usuario_id =:usuario_id");
        query.setParameter("usuario_id", usuario_id);
        medicamento = (Medicamento) query.getSingleResult();
        JPAUtil.closeEntityManager();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoResultException noResultException) {
    }
    return medicamento;
}
```

Isto é apenas um exemplo brother, note que abri e fechei a em no repositorio, mas na aplicação real eu injeto a em e tenho um produces para isso, escrevi assim apenas para tentar passar a idéia, abraços.